# How to speed-up programs launch with my ssd?

Tags: linux, performance, ssd

I have 2 disks on my machine: ssd and hdd.

`/` mount point is on ssd, `/home` is on hdd. 
`C:/` on my Windows 10 is on ssd, too.

It seems to me that some programs (like Chromium web browser) launch much slower than their analogs inside my Windows 10.

Chromium inside my Linux takes about 3 seconds for cold launch, and Chrome (Windows) takes about 0.5 second for cold launch.

The only reasonable solution (I think) is to mount `/home` to ssd, too. Am I right? Because 'Chromium' folder on hdd has weight of 400mb...

Comment: You could try running `iostat -k 5` command to see how much it loads from the different disks during startup.

Comment: Chrome may autostart itself in the background on Windows boot, which would make it difficult to compare startup time.

Comment: @eblock, yes I see... Should I delete the question, or you place your comment as answer?

Comment: Chrome NEQ Chromium. Chrome could also be configured to preload at boot in Windows. I'd suggest checking that before drawing any conclusions. Also, clean your cache on each.

Comment: It's clear that chrome NEQ chromium, I just wanted to point out that some of the browser data are within the user's home directory, e.g. the firefox profile in most (?) linux distros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some user related data of your browser is in `/home` (e.g. `~/.config/chromium/` or `~/.cache/google-chrome/`), so it runs on your hdd. Mounting it on ssd should increase your performance.